# Как передать ссылку на this?

Tags: c++, классы

Есть класс, для упрощения восприятия я убрал все лишнее.

Вопрос такой, в одном методе надо использовать 2 объекта `Demo` чтобы создать третий, но одним из этих двух объектов является объект, метод которого вызывается

```
class Demo {
public:

    // Делаем что-то умное, для упрощения понимания все лишнее удалено
    Demo Process(Demo& _Demo) const {
        Demo outDemo;
        return outDemo;
    }


    Demo Test(Demo& _Demo) const {
        Demo outDemo = Demo();

        outDemo.Process(this); // Тут ошибка
        outDemo.Process(_Demo);

        return outDemo;
    }

};
```

Comment: `outDemo.Process(*this)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вызов будет выглядеть так

```
outDemo.Process(*this);
```

Но у вас метод `Test` является `const`. Поэтому внутри него `*test` - это `const Demo`. Соответственно передать `*this` как `Demo &` вы не сможете. Вызвать ваш `Process` вы сможете только в том случае, если он объявлен как

```
Demo Process(const Demo& _Demo) const
```

Я так понимаю, что  именно это вам и нужно, но вы просто забыли добавить этот `const`.

Comment: Спасибо. Ох, только мне показалось, что я понял как работает `const`, но нет, не понял

Answer (score 2):

Если `Process` принимает `const Demo &`, то правильно так:

```
Demo Test(Demo& _Demo) const {
    Demo outDemo = Demo();

    outDemo.Process(*this);
    outDemo.Process(_Demo);

    return outDemo;
}
```